# How do I edit the HTML for a part of a panel?

Tags: 7, theming, panels

I am new to Drupal and need to style a blank page. The page has some content in it, but I need to make some little adjustments to the html (.tpl?) files.

The page uses a Panelizer variant with 2 columns. I want to add some HTML to one of the items in one of those columns (a 'mini panel').

On which file .tpl in my theme's directory would I make these HTML changes?

Comment: when you say HTML changes do you mean theming or content changes?

Comment: @longboardnode theming

Comment: I believe you will need to add (or confirm it exists) template name suggestions in your template.php, then create a template for your panel/panes as outlined in this [tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/node/1678810)

Comment: did you get this figured out?